# Can we edit the screen cast message in android? Current text - "exposing sensitive info during casting/recording"

Tags: java, android, screen-capture, screensharing, android-mediaprojection

Is it possible to edit the warning message that pops up when we start screen sharing in Android? The message is different for different OS devices.

For OS 10 -
[Image for message shown in OS 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9un8e.jpg)

Comment: Please elaborate on your non-malicious reasons to change that warning.

Comment: Haha. Just wanted to provide more specific information regarding the prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you can't, this prompt is for users safety, can't/shouldn't be disabled/changed